# How to convert multiple date rows into a date range of continuous dates?

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.7

| id | load_date |
| --- | --- |
| 123 | 2021-03-01 |
| 123 | 2021-02-01 |
| 123 | 2021-01-01 |
| 123 | 2020-12-31 |
| 123 | 2020-11-13 |
| 123 | 2020-05-14 |
| 123 | 2020-04-16 |
| 123 | 2019-01-16 |

These are the list of dates i have for one particular member I want to convert it into the date range of continuous dates(based on month & year)

**Expected Result:**

| Member_StartDate | Member_TermDate |
| --- | --- |
| 2019-01-16 | 2019-01-16 |
| 2020-04-16 | 2020-05-14 |
| 2020-11-13 | 2021-03-01 |

I want the result using sql qry for mysql5.7
Any help on this would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you know if a date is a Start or term date?

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (The answer will depend on the product used.)

Comment: I am using MySQL 5.7 version.
start date and Term date is determine by the continuity of the dates, like in this case the minimum date was 2019-01 so first start date was 2019-01 and after that no date till 2020-04 so first end date is also 2019-01 and the next start date is 2020-04.

Comment: Any other doubts please let me know.

Comment: How come 2019-01-16 can't be paired with 2020-04-16, when 2020-11-13 is paired with 2021-03-01?

Comment: because the start date and end date is determined by when there is a break in the continuity because after 2019-01 there is no date till 2020-04 so we re taking end date also 2019-01 and 2020-11-13 is paired with 2021-03-01 because in that after Nov date is there for DEc Jan, Feb, Mar continuously .

Comment: Do you mean a month with no date at all is considered as a break in continuity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is rather straight forward grouping in 8.0

```
select patient_id,  min(load_date) s,  max(load_date) e
from (
   select t.*, 
      sum(seq) over(partition by patient_id order by load_date) grp
   from (
      select *,
         lag(monthstart, 1, DATE_ADD(monthstart, interval -1 month)) over(partition by patient_id order by load_date) <> DATE_ADD(monthstart, interval -1 month) seq
      from (
            select *, DATE_ADD(load_date, interval - day(load_date)+1 day) monthstart
            from events
           )t
       ) t
    )t
group by patient_id, grp
order by patient_id, min(load_date)
```

Translated it back to 5.7 :

```
select patient_id,  min(load_date) s,  max(load_date) e
from (
     select *, 
        (select sum(seq)
         from(
             select *, 
                not exists(
                   select 1 
                   from events e2
                   where DATE_ADD(t.monthstart, interval -1 month) = DATE_ADD(e2.load_date, interval - day(e2.load_date)+1 day) and t.patient_id = e2.patient_id
                          ) seq
             from (
                  select *, DATE_ADD(load_date, interval - day(load_date)+1 day) monthstart
                  from events
                  ) t
              ) t 
         where t.patient_id = e.patient_id and t.load_date <= e.load_date) grp
     from events e
     ) t
group by patient_id, grp
order by patient_id, min(load_date)
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=b418c6e9a06f3f144da2ab69281e4506)